# Can you assign a wildcard to a variable using NMAKE?

Tags: makefile, nmake

I come from a UNIX background so I'm used to being able to do things like this in GNU/Make:

```
SRC=$(wildcard src/*.c)
OBJ=$(SRC:.c=.o)

all: $(OBJ)
    ...
```

I'm wondering if something roughly equivalent to be accomplished in Microsoft NMAKE. I've got the following simple NMAKE Makefile:

```
all: obj\a.obj obj\b.obj obj\c.obj 

{src\}.c{obj\}.obj:
    cl /c $** /Fo$@
```

This works fine. It takes all the source files from `src/`, and compiles them to their equivalents in `obj/`. However, I'd like to condense the default target down to a wildcard like `obj/*.obj` so that I don't have to write out all the object files manually.

Is this possible in NMAKE? I've checked through the NMAKE documentation pretty thoroughly and it doesn't seem to describe anything like what I want to do.

**UPDATE**:

I managed to get the effect I wanted using the accepted solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167004/using-nmake-with-wildcards-in-the-makefile) as reference, and using the following Makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES: .c .obj

obj_files=$(**:.c=.obj)
all: src\*.c
    @$(MAKE) $(obj_files:src=obj)

{src\}.c{obj\}.obj:
    cl /c $< /Fo$@
```

This works using the `obj\` subfolder as the output directory. The `$**` macro is expended within the `all` target.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to wildcard all `.c` files in the `src\` subfolder, and compile them to `.obj` output in the `obj\` subfolder using the following Makefile:

```
.SUFFIXES: .c .obj

obj_files=$(**:.c=.obj)
all: src\*.c
    @$(MAKE) $(obj_files:src=obj)

{src\}.c{obj\}.obj:
    cl /c $< /Fo$@
```

`obj_files` has to be defined with the `$**` macro (which will expand in the `all` target) because I needed to do a double string substitution in order to change the directory name and the file suffix. So far, all the resources I've found only specify how to do a single string substitution.